# SQL Multiple Date Column, Value Bucket

Tags: c#, sql

Please help with this SQL Table Query, I Have a Table Like

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|  DateCol1   DateCol2   DateCol3   DateCol4  |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2014-10-01    null       null    2014_10_04 |
| 2014_10_02 2014_10_01    null    2014_10_04 |
| 2014_10_02    null    2014_10_01 2014_10_04 |
| 2014_10_02    null    2014_10_01    null    |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

If the user is giving input like FromDate = '2014-10-01' and ToDate = '2014-10=05'
 I have To Show Like

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ActivityDate DateCol1_Cnt DateCol2_Cnt DateCol3_Cnt DateCol4_Cnt |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-10-01         1          1               2           0      |
| 2014-10-02         3          0               0           0      |
| 2014-10-03         0          0               0           0      | 
| 2014-10-04         0          0               0           3      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

what i have to show is number  of activity in a Particluar date

what i did so far is

```
Select 'Date1_ACty' Activity ,dateColumn1 Activity_Date, Count(1) Activity_count
From MyTable where dateColumn1 between @FromDate and @ToDate 

union all 

Select 'Date2_ACty' Activity ,dateColumn2 Activity_Date, Count(1) Activity_count
From MyTable where dateColumn2 between @FromDate and @ToDate

union all .....
```

So Far For Remaining column

Please help me with good solution

Problem is I am Getting `DateCol_Acty`, `DateCo2_Acty` etc as column values  not as column  itself :(

Comment: In the mock results that you showed, why does 2014-10-02 appear twice? it is supposed to be 2014-10-04, right? You also showed in the mock results the date '2014-10-03', but you don't have any records as such, which means you need to have a date table of some sort where you can align that against via  left join...

Comment: Yep Sorry its 2014-10-04.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
declare @table table(id int, date1 date, date2 date, date3 date, date4 date)

declare @min date = '2014-10-01', @max date = '2014-10-04';

insert into @table
values
(1, '2014-10-01', null, null, '2014-10-04'),
(2, '2014-10-02', '2014-10-01', null, '2014-10-04'),
(3, '2014-10-02', null, '2014-10-01', '2014-10-04'),
(4, '2014-10-02', null, '2014-10-01', null);

with date1
as (
    select date1 date_,
        count(*) count_
    from @table
    where date1 between @min
            and @max
    group by date1
    ),
date2
as (
    select date2 date_,
        count(*) count_
    from @table
    where date2 between @min
            and @max
    group by date2
    ),
date3
as (
    select date3 date_,
        count(*) count_
    from @table
    where date3 between @min
            and @max
    group by date3
    ),
date4
as (
    select date4 date_,
        count(*) count_
    from @table
    where date4 between @min
            and @max
    group by date4
    ),
dates
as (
    select @min date_
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, date_)
    from dates
    where dateadd(day, 1, date_) <= @max
    )
select d.date_,
    ISNULL(d1.count_, 0) DateCol1_Cnt,
    ISNULL(d2.count_, 0) DateCol2_Cnt,
    ISNULL(d3.count_, 0) DateCol3_Cnt,
    ISNULL(d4.count_, 0) DateCol4_Cnt
from dates d
left join date1 d1 on d1.date_ = d.date_
left join date2 d2 on d2.date_ = d.date_
left join date3 d3 on d3.date_ = d.date_
left join date4 d4 on d4.date_ = d.date_;
```

Comment: Note: The contiguous date recursive sub-query will fail for ranges over 100 days. To get around this you would need to build a function that performs a loop to create the contiguous date range table.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe doing an`UNPIVOT`followed by a new`PIVOT`would work? It's not beautiful, but it seems to get the correct results I think, except for missing the empty dates, but that could be fixed by left joining a column with all dates in the range.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59db3/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int, DateCol1 date, DateCol2 date, DateCol3 date, DateCol4 date);
insert t values 
(1, '2014-10-01', null, null, '2014-10-04'),
(2, '2014-10-02', '2014-10-01', null, '2014-10-04'),
(3, '2014-10-02', null, '2014-10-01', '2014-10-04'),
(4, '2014-10-02', null, '2014-10-01', null);
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @FromDate date = '2014-10-01', @ToDate date = '2014-10-05'

SELECT 
    ActivityDate, 
    DateCol1 AS DateCol1_Cnt, 
    DateCol2 AS DateCol2_Cnt, 
    DateCol3 AS DateCol3_Cnt, 
    DateCol4 AS DateCol4_Cnt    
FROM (
 SELECT d, Dates AS ActivityDate, dates as d2
 FROM (SELECT DateCol1, DateCol2, DateCol3, DateCol4 FROM t) AS p
 UNPIVOT (Dates FOR d IN (DateCol1, DateCol2, DateCol3, DateCol4)) AS unpvt
 ) derived
PIVOT (COUNT(d2) FOR d IN (DateCol1, DateCol2, DateCol3, DateCol4)) pvt
WHERE ActivityDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59db3/2/0)**:

```
| ACTIVITYDATE | DATECOL1_CNT | DATECOL2_CNT | DATECOL3_CNT | DATECOL4_CNT |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|   2014-10-01 |            1 |            1 |            2 |            0 |
|   2014-10-02 |            3 |            0 |            0 |            0 |
|   2014-10-04 |            0 |            0 |            0 |            3 |
```

Comment: Performance wise doing pivot, Is it acceptable? against table Contains lacks of records.

Comment: @Nishanth I can't say really; I guess doing unpivot/pivot might be expensive but I didn't test performance. Try it and find out if it is acceptable in your environment.